# vBulletin - MySQL server has gone away and table is marked as crashed

Tags: mysql, vbulletin

have some problems with server which run 5 years stable.
there is a vbulletin 3 forum running on the server.
i get crashed tables and MySQL server has gone away errors. not sure if lost connection can cause crashed tables or there is another reason for it.
there is no my.cnf file, so must be default mysql config, no big load. sometimes if i click a link i immediately get a white page, after reload page works fine - in log there is then a MySQL server has gone away error.

Answer (score 0):

No a lost connection can not do that. But if MySQL crashes then you can get server has gone away, and the crash can corrupt the table.

You need to find out why MySQL is crashing. Worst case scenario is a bad hard disk - I hope you have good backups. If not do it NOW!